# Hello User, Userid is not defined

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, error, sharepoint-on-prem

I am using below code. I am getting an error:

> `Userid` is not defined.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var loginName = "";
var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
GetCurrentUser();

function GetCurrentUser() {
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";

var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

$.ajax({
  url : requestUri,
  contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
  headers : requestHeaders,
  success : onSuccess,
  error : onError
  });
}

function onSuccess(data, request) {
    var loginName = data.d.Title;
    alert("Hello " + loginName);

    // to set the "hello username" into the page
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Hello " + loginName;
    }

function onError(error) {
  alert(error);
  }

</script>

<div id="name"></div>
```

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? At which line you are getting an error?

Comment: Try add $(document).ready(function () { before vars     https://lixuan0125.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/sharepoint-2013-get-current-user-loginname-using-jsom-rest/

Comment: I am using Sharepoint 2013 and the document.ready has now been added but still does not work

Comment: pass the userId parameter through the function call GetCurrentUser(userID); and inturn accept the parameter GetCurrentUser(userID){...

Answer (score 1):

The code works well in my environment. You’d better debug it yourself.

Or you could try to use this rest endpoint ” /_api/web/currentuser”.

Demo:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    GetCurrentUser();

    function GetCurrentUser() {
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser";

    var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

    $.ajax({
      url : requestUri,
      contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
      headers : requestHeaders,
      success : onSuccess,
      error : onError
      });
    }

    function onSuccess(data, request) {
        var loginName = data.d.Title;
        alert("Hello " + loginName);

        // to set the "hello username" into the page
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Hello " + loginName;
        }

    function onError(error) {
      alert(error);
      }

    </script>

<div id="name"></div>
```